# isalpha() function lets through Latin letters although the locale is set to Russian

Tags: c++, locale, cyrillic

In my program I'm trying to count the frequencies of Cyrillic letters in the text.

I'm checking whether the letter is Cyrillic alphabet letter this way:

```
std::locale loc("Russian");
char monogram;
....
if (isalpha(monogram, loc)) {
....
}
```

The problem is this condition lets through some letters from Latin alphabet.

I can't lose efficiency by previously filtering the whole text (it's a large file). Anyways, I do not see a way to do filtering, except that monotonously comparing every letter from the text to every letter from the alphabet to find a match. That is obviously not the best way...

Comment: Which charset is the text stored as? UTF-8, Unicode, Windows-1251, KOI8?

Comment: It is stored as ANSI

Comment: The [ANSI](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html) charset contains no Cyrillic characters.

Comment: I guess, it's the same as Windows-1251 (in Notepad++, but in standard Notepad it's ANSI). Otherwise, how come all the Cyrillic letters got their frequencies calculated? It's just that some Latin letters got their frequencies calculated, too.